# Is there a way to extract cookies from the Firefox cookies file?

Tags: java, sqlite, firefox, cookies, oauth

I'm not sure if this is possible but is there a way to grab the cookie from yahoo from Firefox's cookies.sqlite file and then use that information in a Java program?  When I log into yahoo, I told it to leave me logged in.  Since the browser thinks I'm still logged in, that info is stored in a cookie (I assume).

I saw yahoo has their [developer's API](http://developer.yahoo.com/fantasysports/guide/) and some OAuth library.  To be able to use OAuth to log in, I would need to register my program but I don't want to register unless I have to.  I found this [post from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610896/how-to-use-sqlite-to-read-data-from-the-firefox-cookies-file) on how to use sqlite.exe to view the file.  However, the file looks like gibberish (to a human) and I can't tell what entry is my cookie.

Is there another way to parse this file to get my yahoo cookie and use it in a Java program?  Do I have to register my "secret" program with yahoo to use OAuth properly to log into yahoo?  Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: This seems like a disproportionately complicated way to do things, considering it probably won't work anyway. Why not just register and be done?

Comment: @Mike W B/c I didn't want to read the whole Terms of Service closely in case I signed my life away.  =)  I kinda skimmed it and I read something about possibly being charged in the future for using their API, which I don't want happening.  If I have to, I'll register but if I don't have to, I don't want to.

Comment: Oh, if someone knows how to do this on Chrome instead of FF, I'm all ears too.

Comment: @MikeW Too bad for me. I tried signing up for an API key but it doesn't proceed past the app registration page. I think there's a problem on Yahoo's end but no on has replied to me via the forum. Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are stored in an sqlite file, so this worked for me:

```
$ sqlite3 ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/cookies.sqlite
sqlite> select name,value from moz_cookies where host="bugs.kde.org" and name LIKE "Bugzill%";
```

My use case is to extract the bugzilla cookie in order to give it to a script.
For other use cases, adjust the SQL query accordingly, obviously.

Comment: This only works when Firefox is not running. If running, I get `Error: database is locked`. Because Firefox opens the cookie db in a state that does not allow a `SHARED` (read-only) lock, I'm not sure how to read when Firefox is running. So this is great for some use cases, but not for mine.

Comment: @Cliff You can simply copy the file to other place to open. The real issue of this method is it doesn't include **session cookies** which required in some sites.

Comment: I was pointing out that, as written, accessing the sqlite file does not work in all cases. In the script I wrote, I copy the file before acting on it.

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox, try this.  It's based on using the session recovery file Firefox stores.  This is bash syntax, not Java, but can probably be adapted pretty easily.

`grep -o '{"host":"<HOSTNAME>"[^}]*}' $HOME/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js`

That should dump out each cookie as a JSON entry that is associated with whatever you put in for `<HOSTNAME>`.  You can adjust beyond that to extract the specific cookie you want.

*Note:* If you have more than one FF profile, you may need to adjust the `*.default` portion.  The directory name is stored in `.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini`, but extracting it from there is really overkill if only a single profile exists.

Comment: Looks like this file is now called `recovery.jsonlz4` but I'm not sure how to read it...

Comment: @DavidFaure Try `lz4 -d recovery.jsonlz4 | grep -o '{"host":"<HOSTNAME>"[^}]*}' `  The `lz4 -d` should decompress the file.  If the file format changed internally, you may need to adjust the grep argument.

Comment: `lz4` didn't work for me, but there is a package called `lz4json` which provides `lz4jsoncat` that worked. Looks like this package is available since 20.04.

Comment: To complement what @RobieBasak wrote above, here's the link to repo: https://github.com/andikleen/lz4json